# document.getElementById in toString

Tags: javascript, html, tostring

**edit**
Found my answers [here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/Object-to-Primitive-Conversions-in-JavaScript). Bottom line: `toString/valueOf` can only return primitive types. So here the lack of native getters in javascript shows, I suppose.

I would like to use the following simple function in an elementwrapper:

```
function ElGetter(id){
       var id = id;
       return {
         set: function(nwid){id = nwid;},
         toString: function(){return document.getElementById(id);},
         valueOf: function(){return document.getElementById(id);}
       };
}
var myEl = ElGetter('myId');
console.log(myEl.innerHTML); //=> undefined
```

But I can't get it to work. Is it a DOM/javascript restriction or am I missing something? Normally it works, as in:

```
function Tester(){
    var x = 1;
    return {
   toString: function(){return x},
   valueOf: function(){return x}
 }
}
var myTest = Tester();
console.log(myTest); //=> 1
```

Comment: ^^ In the above snippet, you have a lowercase 'e' while calling ElGetter function. I hope thats not the case in the actual code.

Comment: it's not. I'll edit, thanks for bringing it to my attention

Comment: @KooiInc It' simple. The `myEl` object does not have an `innerHTML` property. DOM element node objects have this property, but `myEl` is not such an object.

Comment: @KooiInc Also, why are you declaring a local `id` variable and setting it to the passed in argument? I think the argument alone should be fine...

Comment: @Šime Vidas: concerning id: you're right. I distilled this from a more complex constructor, forgot to remove it. Concerning myEl: if toString was able to return an Object, innerHTML should have been a property. I have now found out that toString can't return Objects.

Comment: @Kooilnc: if this is a constructor, why are you returning something and why aren't you using the ´new´ keyword? this code smells. just saying.

Comment: @KooiInc Yea, but your code is: `myEl.innerHTML`. String coercion only occurs after that code is evaluated (and it evaluates to the undefined value). This would work: `myEl.toString().innerHTML`. This also: `myEl.valueOf().innerHTML`. Those two work, since both `toString` and `valueOf` return the DOM object.

Comment: @KooiInc And yes, `toString` can return objects (if you define it to behave in such a manner, and you did in your above code). `var foo = myEl.toString();` The `foo` variable is a DOM element object.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: myEl.toString() can return an Object, that's right. But you can't *overwrite* the native toString and use it as a sort of a getter for an Object, and that's what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, `toString()` return a **string**. It can't (by design) return complex object.

So, by returning `document.getElementById(id)` you return the **string** `[object]` (IE) or `[object HTMLDivElement]` (Chrome) - that string has no such property as `innerHTML`.

You can do this though:

```
toString: function(){return document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;},
```

And it will show the inner HTML of the element.

Comment: wasn't after innerHTML, but the complete HTMLObject. Your answer is ok but not complete. See my edits.

Comment: @KooiInc I know, but it's not possible to get the complete object using the native `toString()` method. Is your problem solved now?

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(myEl.valueOf().innerHTML);
```

I don't get it, why would following object:

```
{
   set: function(nwid){id = nwid;},
   toString: function(){return document.getElementById(id);},
   valueOf: function(){return document.getElementById(id);}
}
```

have a property `innerHTML`? It seems you are somehow counting on the toString method being implicitly called but instead of returning a string it returns a DOM object. What on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: i have my reasons. Found the answer already, just not thought hard enough

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery?

$('myID').innerHTML();

Comment: I use my own framework. Did'nt look for innerHTML, wanted the whole HTMLObject